# Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function(…)

Tags: mysql, reactjs

Using mysqljs, I want to query some data from my local db and render them with react. 
This is what I did so far:

```
import React from 'react';
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'pep'
});

connection.connect();
var Menu=React.createClass({
    data : function (){
        connection.query('Select * from '+this.props.table, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(rows);
        })
    },
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.data}>click</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
export default Menu;
```

(Another file is using the Menu component and passing the props to Menu)

Nothing is displayed and it came with this error in the bowser's console:

```
Connection.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function
    at Connection.connect (webpack:///./~/mysql/lib/Connection.js?:91:13)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/Menu.js?:24:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2983:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:556:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87:20)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/Combobox.js?:18:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3121:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:556:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87:20)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/App.js?:18:17)
```

Why is that? How can I fix this or what should I do in order to get my data from the db using react?

Answer (score 8):

mysqljs [relies on Node's net library](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/9be699132782d4fffc8695545b104a9458957798/lib/Connection.js#L3). You don't have this API in your browser, so you won't be able to use the library this way without major changes.

You shouldn't establish a direct connection from the client's browser to your backing database anyway, as your mysql database server is not necessarily built for this use case. Instead, publish your data via a dedicated web server as [RESTful web services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671132/3836229). You could for example use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify) framework for that purpose.